# magento 1.9.0.1 how do i show default new product after ajax call to specific category then back to default product

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

i'm new to magento.
In home page i have 2tab 1)new arrival 2)popular

i created a module called popular and when user clicked on "popular tab" it will display product from a category called popular through jquery ajax i have done it successfully but problem is when user want to back/click "new arrival" tab i cant restore or show new arrival as default page by ajax.

My code is shown below

in controller i written

```
public function loadcategoryproduct1Action()
{
     echo $this->getLayout() ->createBlock('catalog/product_list') ->setTemplate('catalog/product/new.phtml') ->toHtml();
}
```

and the ajax part

```
function loadCategoryProducts1() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'popular/index/loadcategoryproduct1',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(products) {
           alert(products);
           jQuery('.product_area').html(products);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you have an ajax request for new products also? otherwise you should be able to always have the new products tab as a link, which would reload the first page

Comment: yes,i want to when user click on "new arrival" it will show new product by ajax

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an ajax function for each tab like so:

**Controller**

```
public function loadcategoryproduct2Action()
{
     echo $this->getLayout() ->createBlock('catalog/product_list') ->setTemplate('catalog/product/popular.phtml') ->toHtml();
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function loadCategoryProducts2() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'popular/index/loadcategoryproduct2',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(products) {
           alert(products);
           jQuery('.product_area').html(products);
        }
    });
}
```

Or make a general ajax-request function to send in productname and template

Comment: hi Forsius thanks for your response but i'm successfully completed the  popular portion but cant the "new arrival" portion and popular portion  done like you suggested

Comment: What does your ajax response contain? console.log(products);

Comment: Make sure the paths are correctly spelled in this line:
$this->getLayout() ->createBlock('catalog/product_list') ->setTemplate('catalog/product/new.phtml') ->toHtml();
and that this actually produces a HTML-string